# How to program PORT B C D for ATmega328 for normal digital in/out or Alternate function?

Tags: atmega

I want to know how to set the PORTS either to simple digital in/out or to alternate function like interrupt, custom input, etc.

I read about PORTxn, DDRx, PINx to set digital in/out. I read the Alternate function starting at page 89 of datasheet. But, I have no idea how to set the 3 PORTS to Alternate function or normal digital in/out.

Answer (score 0):

The ports are normal GPIO unless you enable a peripheral which then overrides the pin for that alternate function.

So you don't really have to configure the IO pin between GPIO and alternate function, it gets configured for you.

Comment: Thanks Justme
I am very new on this, excuse me in asking very basic question.
So what you said is even if I program DDRx register, If I go to specific Alternate function register to set it as alternate function, the DDRx information would be OVERWRITTEN. So I have to go to the specific Alternate function to set the port? Thanks

Comment: @Alan0354 - not overwritten but may be ignored. Be careful about the GPIO direction when using SPI as it can affect the SPI behavior.